# Edit text/comments of rmarkdown and knitr reports without rerunning code

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

I love `knitr` & `rmarkdown`, but I often find myself in situations where  I have a lengthy report that takes some nontrivial amount of time to run.  After it's generated, I notice my inevitable typos in text.  However, re-knitting everything to just fix a couple typos (just in text, not code) takes a long time and seems avoidable.  I was about to start taking a hack at developing my own solution to this, but I'm thinking it's the kind of thing that could already have a mature solution which would likely be more robust than the one I'd build.

I'm wondering if there is solution out there within `knitr` or third party that would allow me to edit just the text of my reports without rerunning code, generating plots and outputs etc.  I know, I can simply edit the generated html text, but then those changes must be replicated in the R/Rmd code that generated it, or they get out of sync.  I'm envisioning a function like this:

- **argument 1:** the R/Rmd script with text edits (no code changes)... perhaps a warning is generated when code chunks change
- **argument 2:** the html output file from the last time the R script in argument was knitted without the text edits.
- **return:** the html report (argument 2) updated with the comments in the R/Rmd script (argument 1).

I use the `cache` option sometimes for large datasets.  I toggle `eval` and `echo` on and off when developing if I'm just working on the text of my report.  However, I'm looking for a function that would take care of all this for me, so one doesn't have to mess with the code and chunk options to make small edits to text.

Comment: Are you sure that you understood the [full power of knitr's cache](http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/cache/)? It "takes care of all this" for you and you "don't have to mess with the code and chunk options".

Comment: @user2706569 - cache option adds a layer of complexity that I'd like to avoid for simple edits.  cache must be specified before running the report and there are considerations ("Important Notes" section in your [link](http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/cache/)). It also keeps a large copy of your objects which I'd like to avoid.

Comment: Not directly to your question, but perhaps you could break your large document into child scripts and then just re-run the scripts where you have made text edits.  Yihui Xie's book explains this at pages 83-84.  Along those lines, perhaps external references to your time-consuming chunks would let you globally "turn them off" when you just do text edits.

Comment: @ajb - I don't think the cache is "complicated" because there is a default local cache directory that does not need to "be specified". But I think I see your point about the cache: The cache system will cache the *R* objects (etc.), but I don't think it caches the outputted HTML (or markdown, etc). So re-running knitr *may* still re-render all plots, tables, etc. based on the loaded cached R objects. Even re-running the knit *without* any edits can still be slow if the cached R objects are large.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an interim solution that lets you retain the speed of making changes directly to the rendered text, but you have to do a little work after you're done making changes.

Assuming the following files:

- **`input.knitr`** is the original Knitr file with text and code integrated.
- **`output.html`** is the resulting HTML code that has been rendered by Knitr.

Consider making direct text edits to `output.html` and then running something like [Meld](http://meldmerge.org/) visual merge tool:

```
meld output.html input.knitr
```

Then manually select the edits in `output.html` that are new and should be fixed in the original source `input.knitr`. Tools such as Meld do a pretty good job of aligning the texts so that the chunks and knitted output will appear as large "changes" that, in practice, you would ignore. You would focus on the small changes in the non-chunk sections.

Comment: Interesting - I was thinking of having this theoretical function edit the raw html code directly without working on the rendered html at all.  I'll look into this.  Thanks